# How to create a data frame with repeated values basis value taken from a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list say List X that has 26 members, say A...Z

How to create a data frame with one column such that A comes 100 times than B comes 100 times and so on?

I will then have to join this data frame with 2600 values in another data frame which don't have the alphabet references but i know that they are in order and each alphabet has 100 values. For simulation you can create a data frame of 2600 random values.

It's an easily reproducible example. Appreciate your help with R code? Or can it be done through complete cases option with one data frame having 26 values and other has 2600 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for the option: *How to create a data frame with one column such that A comes 100 times than B comes 100 times and so on... ?*:

```
#Data
List <- as.list(LETTERS)
#Code
x <- as.data.frame(do.call(c,lapply(List,function(x) rep(x,100))))
rownames(x)<-NULL
names(x) <- 'v1'
table(x$v1)
```

Output of first variable in new dataframe `x`:

```
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 
  Y   Z 
100 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to replicate, use `rep` after `unlist`ing.  By this way, it is more efficient than looping over the `list` and `rep`licating each element

```
data.frame(col1 = rep(unlist(X), each = 100))
```

Comment: i want the list values to repeat, please carefully read the question